# Вызов функции MXML приложения из AS класса

Tags: xml, функции, actionscript, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Собственно вопрос описан в заголовке, как вызвать функцию MXML приложения из AS класса.

Пробовал просто по имени конструктора, но не получается, говорит, что такого не существует. Хотя обращение между AS классами свободное, классы лежат в пустом пакете, т.е доступны друг другу.

Как это можно устроить другим способом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вариант синглтона (если нельзя обратиться к экземляру)

В mxml подписываемся на creationComplete и создаем статическое поле instance:

```
<s:MyClass             creationComplete = "creationCompleteHandler(event)" >
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   public static var instance:MyClass = null;

   protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:Object=null):void
   {
     instance = this;
   }
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>

  // Место вызова:

  MyClass.instance.myMethod();
```

Естественно обращаться к нему до creationComplete экземпляра MyClass не стоит.